# Как выровнять по центру список рубрик в wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Создал отдельную страницу в Wordpress и хочу вывести на ней список рубрик. Я использовал функцию `wp_list_categories`.

Все выводит только не могу применить стили чтобы рубрики выводились по центру.

Вот мой код:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="illustration">Пример текста

        <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&child_of=54');  ?> 

    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

В css прописал следующий код:

```
.illustration {
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid green;
   }
```

Comment: Ну а можно посмотреть все `css` свойство `illustration`?

Comment: Откройте панель разработчика и посмотрите код! Что находится внутри `<div class="illustration">Пример текста` ? Сразу же текст или все же еще какие-то генерируемые `div` или `p`, для которых могут быть заданы другие стили!

Comment: Сделал вот так. И все заработало.

Comment: <?php
    /*
    Template Name: illustration
    */
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<?php get_header(); ?>
 
 </head>
    <body>

 <div class="illustration">Пример текста
 
  <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&child_of=54');  ?> 
  
 </div>
 
 
<?php get_footer(); ?>


    </body>
</html>